# Show only output from recent date using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a query where I display only the keys from the most current date.

This is my table

```
 vkey         Date
V-12345     1966-06-14
555658      1986-03-31
V-5666      2011-11-11
V-8533      2011-11-11 
V-1111111   2012-02-02 
5555501     2012-09-09 
V-8236      2013-06-25
V-8533      2015-05-05
V-122154    2016-07-26
V-8562      2015-09-05
V-8533      2016-07-26
```

I should get

```
vkey        Date
V-8533      2016-07-26
V-122154    2016-07-26
```

I have tried

```
 SELECT vkey, MAX("date") as "date" 
 FROM [Testing].[dbo].[VKeySTIG_ BreakDown] 
 GROUP BY "VKEY"
```

but this gives me the most recent date from each key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be

```
 SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES vKey, 
                          [Date]
 FROM [Testing].[dbo].[VKeySTIG_ BreakDown] 
 ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query ... it works by first getting the max date and then finding the rows corresponding to that date

```
select * from FROM [Testing].[dbo].[VKeySTIG_ BreakDown] A INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT  MAX("date") as "Maxdate" 
 FROM [Testing].[dbo].[VKeySTIG_ BreakDown] 
) B ON A."date" = B."Maxdate"
```